# _tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "background.png"

Tags: python, image, tkinter

```
root.title("Broken Rootery")
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.config(bg="black")
close = Button(root, text="Quit", fg="white", bg="black",font="System", bd=0, command=root.quit)
close.pack(side=BOTTOM)
img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='background.png', master=root)
lab = tkinter.Label(root, image=img)
lab.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\BS1\brokenroot.py", line 48, in <module>
    img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file='background.png', master=root)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "background.png"
```

Please i need help.

Comment: The image may not be a PNG image.

Comment: Is this actually a png image, or is it some other format like jpg that you only renamed to .png?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file_path)`. For this you need to import modules like this: `from PIL import ImageTk, Image`. With this, your code would look like:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Broken Rootery")
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.config(bg="black")
close = tk.Button(root, text="Quit", fg="white", bg="black",font="System", bd=0, command=root.quit)
close.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("background.png"))
lab = tk.Label(root, image=img)
lab.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Note here that `ImageTk` belongs to the `PIL` package.